# Input onChange is not working using ref value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, dom-events

I have a code for uploading excel file by clicking a button. So when I select a file by clicking button and again reselect same file by clicking, the `onChange()` event is not recognizing it.

My reference value :

```
  this.inputFile = React.createRef(null)
```

My Upload Button :

```
            <input
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            ref={this.inputFile}
            onChange={this.onFileChange}
            type="file"
            accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, 
            application/vnd.ms-excel"
          />

          <div className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={this.onButtonClick} >
              Upload File
          </div>
```

My two onChange and onClick methods :

```
  onFileChange =(e)=> {
   this.setState({
    selectedFile:e.target.files[0],
  })
  };

  onButtonClick = () => {
    this.inputFile.current.click();
  };
```

Comment: It's normal. Selecting the same file doesn't re-trigger the onChange event.

Comment: So whats the way around if i want to select that file again.

Comment: You can set the value of the input to `null` on click.

Comment: onchange event itself says , change in previous data/file . if you are uploading same file it won't trigger onchange event. you need to clear previous values to detect this event

Answer (score 3):

If you select the same file, `onchange` event won't re-trigger. But if you insist on doing it, you need to remove the current value of the input on each click:

```
<input
  style={{ display: "none" }}
  ref={this.inputFile}
  onChange={this.onFileChange}
  type="file"
  accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, 
            application/vnd.ms-excel"
  onClick={this.clearFileInput} // ADD HERE
/>

<div className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={this.onButtonClick} >
  Upload File
</div>
```

```js
clearFileInput = () => {
  this.inputFile.current.value = null;
}
```

Comment: if i set inputfile = null, then the next time I will call onButtonClick() ...it will throw error, because " this.inputFile.current " (TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null).

Comment: No, As I said, you shouldn't set inputFile to null. you should set `this.inputFile.current.value` to null. @ShankarNanda

Comment: yes bro I did same as u mentioned, but still am getting error

Comment: @ShankarNanda Can you send the code you wrote here?

Comment: Thanks making `this.inputFile.current.value = null` helps

Comment: @ShankarNanda That's great :) . So can you please consider marking this answer as accepted? Thanks